# Unable to select Custom Checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Unable to Check/Un-check custom checkbox.

Explanation: On commenting out `dispaly:none` I can view, check, uncheck the blue checkbox. But the custom Checkbox cannot be checked or unchecked.

This is the expected output where the blue checkbox is not displayed. However having problem to check or uncheck the custom checkboxes. Your help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you already did with the input type checkbox for the `onChange` event, you should include the click event handler  also for the labels performing the same action:

- `onClick={handleSelectAll}` on the first label
- `onClick={() => onClickDOP(day)}` on the other labels

```
    suggestionsListComponent = (
        <ul>
            <li>
            <Checkbox checked={selectAll} onChange={handleSelectAll} />
            <label
                className="custom-checkbox-label"
                onClick={handleSelectAll}>  <--------
                All
            </label>
            </li>
            {filteredSuggestions.map((day: any, index: any) => {
            return (
                <li key={day.id}>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    className=""
                    name={day?.name}
                    value={day?.name}
                    checked={day.active}
                    onChange={() => onClickDOP(day)}
                />
                <label
                    className="custom-checkbox-label"
                    onClick={() => onClickDOP(day)}  <--------
                >
                    {day?.name}
                </label>
                </li>
            );
            })}
        </ul>
    );
```

Comment: Thank you so so so much. Thank you. I do appreciate your help. .